# CSS Specificity issue in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a `base.css` that has the following CSS:

```
.table thead tr th, table th { 
    text-align:left; 
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #333; 
    padding: 4px; 
    background-color: #EEE; 
    border: #FFF solid; 
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;  
    border-left: #e7e7e7; 
    white-space:nowrap;  }
```

I have included this CSS in my JSP. But I needed different colors than the one in my `base.css` so I declared something like:

```
#demo table.header tr {
    background:#FDBB30
}
```

In my JSP. I had faced this issue before and found out about CSS Specificity. The specificity of the first one is `0,0,1,5` and that of the second is `0,1,1,2`. According to it, the table should render the second CSS. But it's not. Any suggestions.. ? I cannot remove `base.css` I need it for other elements.

My table is like:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <!-- Column Naming for the table -->
      <tr>
         <th class="header">SName</th>
         <th class="header">Report</th>
         <th class="header">Owner</th>
         <th class="header">STime</th>
         <th class="header">SFreq</th>
         <th class="header">SDate</th>
         <th class="header">EDate</th>
         <!-- <th>Action</th> -->
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector is wrong

```
#demo table.header tr
```

First of all I don't see any `demo` id declared there, also `table.header` is incorrect, that means select the `table` with a class `header` but since you are applying that class to `th` the selector will fail.

Call the `class` on `table` element

```
<table class="header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" width="100%" >
```

Also make sure you've a wrapper element, say for example a `div` with an id of `demo`

---

Still not comfortable with above thing, simply use an `id` on your `table` like

```
<table id="change_color" ...>
```

and than use the selector below

```
#change_color thead tr {
   background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEaH6/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of applying custom CSS on `tr`, apply it on `th`. Like this:

```
#demo th.header {
   background:#FDBB30
}
```

Also in your HTML, make sure that you have used `id="demo"` for either your `table` or a `div` containing that `table`.

This [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sfnzm/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the errors in your CSS selector (see other answers), there is also the simple fact that backgrounds in table cells are drawn "on top of" backgrounds in table rows, so they will always override them, no matter if the specificity on the tr is much higher!

If the HTML is

```
<table id="table">
    <tr id="tr"><th>hello</th></tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS is

```css
th {background:cyan}
body table#table tr#tr {background:yellow !important}
```

the background will still be cyan! See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Sfnzm/2/).